# How to retrieve a bean by classname from CDI BeanManager? (an not any children)

Tags: cdi, bean-manager

I'm trying to understand a snippet of code and don't understand the documentation for [CDI BeanManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#resolve-java.util.Set-)

> Bean resolve(Set> beans) 
>   Apply the ambiguous dependency resolution rules to a set of beans.

What are the ambiguous dependency resolution rules?  How does CDI reduce a `Set<Bean> beans` to a single Bean?

I'm running into a slight issue where I want to look up a bean by exact type, but not sure how to do it:

```
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(com.pkg.MyClass.class, annotations);
    Bean<?> bean = bm.resolve(beans);
```

will find my all beans of type `com.pkg.MyClass` - both the exact implementation and any children.  If only children exist in the CDI, then it will return one of the children.  However, I only want to find the exact `com.pkg.MyClass` bean.  If not the exact bean isn't there, I want to return null or throw an exception.

How can tell the bean manager that I only want an exact match when searching for a bean by classname?

Answer (score 2):

Typically to do this, you would annotate the actual implementation with `@Typed` and specify only that type.  See also https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Typed.html

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to read up on the `@Typed` annotation but I don't exactly understand how I can leverage that in my case.  I'm trying to retrieve the bean programmatically, so I wouldn't be annotating a field with that annotation.  So I need to pass it as an annotation to the `getBeans()` call?  Ie: bm.getBeans(com.pkg.MyClass.class, Typed.class)

Comment: No, you would annotate the implementation with `@Typed` so that it is only resolvable as those specific type(s).